# Paused a requestAnimationFrame when click on a button

Tags: javascript, animation, requestanimationframe

Is it possible to pause a `requestAnimationFrame`?
When i click on a specific button, the animation has to be paused.
And by click the button another time the animation has to be continued.

```
public addProgressbar() {
    const progressbar = $('.progressbar__value');
    const max = this.$progressMax;
    const time = (1000 / max) * 5;
    let start = null;
    this.progress = 0;

    const step = timestamp => {
        if (start === null) {
            start = timestamp;
        }
        this.progress = timestamp - start;
        progressbar[0].style.width = Math.min(this.progress / 50, 2000).toFixed() + '%';
        if (this.progress < 5000) {
            requestAnimationFrame(step);
        }
    };
    setTimeout(() => {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: If the code in the question works, I don't understand why you're asking the question.  The code works, doesn't it?

Comment: sry, I edited the text. The code works well, but i need the functionality to paused and continue the animation

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` isn't like `setInterval`, it doesn't run continuously.  In other words: you don't "pause" a request for an animation frame, you can only cancel it.  You can avoid requesting an additional animation frame.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: When i cancel the animation frame for example at 50%, can i start it again at 50%?
If yes, then that would be a good solution for me